# Examples of Vector space whose Basis $\not\subset$ Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

There is a vector space $S$ with basis elements $B$.

**Question**:

- Is it necessary that the $B\subset S$ or can there a case where $B\not\subset S$ ?
- Is [infinite-dimensional Hilbert space](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertSpace.html) ($\mathcal H$ of functions $f:\Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C ,[-\infty,\infty$]), an example of $B\not\subset S$ ?

while writing the 2nd question I am thinking of
**Example:**

let $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4a}}$, $f\in \mathcal H$

This function can be constructed using basis $b(x)=e^{ikx}$ by $$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(k)e^{ikx} dk $$
where $g(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a\pi}}e^{-ak^2}$ is like weight to the basis, will give us $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4a}}$

**Hence we can get  $f\in \mathcal H$ by $b\not \in \mathcal H$**,

$\because$ finite value of inner product or $L^2$ condition of $\mathcal H$, is not satisfied by $b$

**PS:**
$e^{ikx}$ basis can span infinite dimension [Hilbert space](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertSpace.html) by Fourier transform(the above integral), with suitable weight $g(x)$

Comment: the basis elements must belong to the vector space

Comment: Are there some other Vector spaces other then Hilbert space, with $Basis \not\subset Vector space$ ?

Comment: _By defintion_ a basis consists of vectors that are members of the vector space. The task of a basis is to create a one-to-one correspondence between vectors and coordinate tuples. If one of the basis elements is not itself in the vector space, then the coordinate tuple $(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ would not correspond to a vector, and so the purported basis has failed at its most basic job.

Comment: @Troposphere Actually I don't understand you comment but by as much I understood, Hilbert space( Normalizable space) seems to be in contradiction, using $\psi(x)=e^{ikx}$ (non-normalizable, out of hilbert space) and by it's linear combinations (via furier transformation) we can get functions in hilbert space like $\phi (x)=Ae^{ax^2}$

Comment: For an easier example, the zero function is $0 = x + (-x)$ but both $x, -x$ are not in the Hilbert space. Is that your confusion?

Comment: @ Arctic Char but x, -x are not basis of Hilbert space, as they can not span Hilbert space.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170100/basis-functions-do-not-lie-in-the-space-they-form?rq=1 similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically it's incorrect. It's not $B \in S$, rather $B \subset S$. It's for an individual element $\vec b \in B$ that we have $\vec b \in S$.

You can see on [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorBasis.html) that being a subset is given as part of the definition:

> A vector basis of a vector space $V$ is defined as a **subset** $v_1,...,v_n$ of vectors in $V$ that are linearly independent and span $V$.

(bolding added)

$B$ is a basis if $$(\vec v \in S) \leftrightarrow (\exists! c_1,c_2 ... : \vec v = c_1\vec b_1 +c_2\vec b_2 +...)$$ That is, $S$ is the set of all vectors that are a linear combination of the elements of $B$. And $b_1$ clearly is a linear combination: just take $c_1 =1$ and the rest of the coefficients zero. Similarly for the other elements of $B$.

Comment: Your  second condition for $B$ being a basis (the one after Wolfram's) is actually that of a spanning set. Did you mean $\exists!$ (exists unique) instead of $\exists$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and correction. I must have thought like this, in a sense of proving.

Comment: What is Hilbert space? There are many nonisomorphic Hilbert spaces. Also what definition of basis are you using?

Comment: It's unclear to me why the last edit to this answer was approved, as it entirely deviates from the original answerer's intent.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Actually I don't know math term, but I was thinking about, Hilbert space for a free particle.

Comment: @ Jose Avilez my knowledge of math is limited, I have removed physics terms from the previous edit, please suggest anything else.

Comment: I see. Indeed there is only one infinitely-dimensional and separable Hilbert space (up to isomorphism). Mostly our operators are (densely) defined on the square integrable function $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. I must say I had never heard of not normalizable wave functions (because essentially by definition that is a contradiction). But that might be because I am more a mathematician than a physist :)

Comment: @Severin Schraven  Thanks! it's my first encounter with mathematical rigors. But what is the answer to this "question".

Comment: For all notions of basis I know (Hamel or Schauder basis), the basis vectors need to elements of the set. That is because they should in some sense "span" the whole thing. The plane waves that were mentioned do form a Schauder/Hilbert basis if you look at wave function in a box (with periodic boundary conditions) after passing to momentum space. Note that in this case plane waves are indeed square integrable as we are in the finite volume case.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that by [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Definition) a basis for $S$ is a **linearly independent subset** of $S$ which spans $S$, therefore the number of vectors in the basis can't exceed the dimension of $S$.

Comment: actually my question was related this question if u know little quantum mechanics  Let S denote the state space consisting of all realistic wave functions of a particle. Consider the definite momentum states
$$ψp0(x) =  1/(√2Πћ) e (i/ћ) p0x$$

(a)These functions  are part of S and form a basis for S
(b)These functions  are not part of S but form a basis for S
(c)These functions  are part of S but do not  form a basis for S
(d)These functions  are not part of S and do not  form a basis for S     answer given is b but as given psi wave function does not belong to S the how can it be answer

Comment: @user235005 Then we can exclude in any case the option "b" since it is meaningless.

Comment: yes that's what i did.but answer was given as b

Comment: @user235005 For my knowledge it should be a typo. Try to edit your question with these details for some other advice on that form other users.

Comment: thanks @gimusi  for your answer

Comment: This answer makes an assertion that I don't find all that trivial, and which doesn't work unless $S$ is finite-dimensional (and quantum mechanics is full of infinite-dimensional spaces).

Comment: @Accumulation This answer actually works also in infinite-dimensions if you interpret "number of" as "cardinality of". On the other hand we might argue that we don't care that much about Hamel basis (as we don't know any explicite one), but more for Schauder basis in this context.